# Is there a way to change the order of previous recipients in Apple mail?

Tags: mac, mail.app, contacts

John Doe is someone I email often.  John Dee is someone I emailed recently and will probably email again, but not nearly as often.  I don't want to remove John Dee from my previous recipients, but I want John Doe to come up first again for quick compleion.  (I'm *sure* that otherwise I'm going to accidentally send John some mail meant for John.)  I can't find any way to reorder entries in the Previous Recipients window.  Is there any way to make Doe come up first again?

I tried adding Doe but not Dee to my Address Book, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can type Doe instead of John in the address fields (To, Cc, Bcc, Reply-To) when composing an email message.

Comment: True, but I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to think about it so much.  Mail comes back with a default, then a delay, then a list of options.  I'm looking for a way to get control over that default.